# Writting a java class and a driver to test the class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a lot of trouble with this homework problem for my intro to java course.

"Design and implement the class CupDispenser. Each CupDispenser object has a location and keeps track of the number of cups it currently contains. Define two constructors, set and get methods for each data field, and the method toString. Also, define a method getOneCup that simply decrements the number of cups in the dispenser by 1. Demonstrate your class by creating several CupDispenser objects. Also, write a driver to test your CupDispenser class."

I have the bit that decrements the cups by 1, but as far as the constructors and toStrings go I am at a complete loss. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
public class CupDispenser {

    private int nOfCups, initNum;

    public CupDispenser(int num) {
        this.nOfCups = num;     
        this.initNum = num;
    }

    public int decCups () {
        this.nOfCups = this.nOfCups -1;
        return this.nOfCups;
    }
    public int getNumOfCup () {
        return this.initNum;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        CupDispenser decr = new CupDispenser(10);

        for (int i=0; i<decr.getNumOfCup(); i++) {
            System.out.println(decr.decCups());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `How can I show my class by using dispenser objects?` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit more clear. How can I demonstrate my class by creating several CupDispenser objects?

Comment: Skipping the fact that you have called your class `DecrementStackOverflow` and not `CupDispenser` in your example; you can just create as many objects as you like. Either use an `array`, `Collection` or just `CupDispenser dispenser2 = new CupDispenser(123);` again and again with different variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The following are two classes, one is the CupDispenser class where we define our fields, methods, constructor, etc and the other is where instantiate multiple CupDispenser objects with different properties.

```
package q23463540;

public class CupDispenser {

private int numberOfCups;
private String locationOfCups;

public CupDispenser(int numberOfCups, String locationOfCups){
    this.setNumberOfCups(numberOfCups);
    this.setLocationOfCups(locationOfCups);
}

public int getNumberOfCups() {
    return numberOfCups;
}

public void setNumberOfCups(int numberOfCups) {
    this.numberOfCups = numberOfCups;
}

public String getLocationOfCups() {
    return locationOfCups;
}

public void setLocationOfCups(String locationOfCups) {
    this.locationOfCups = locationOfCups;
}

public void decrementCups(){
    numberOfCups--;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String result = ("Number of Cups = " + numberOfCups + ". Location of Cups = " + locationOfCups + ".");

    return result.toString();
}


}

package org.apothem.stackoverflow;

import q23463540.CupDispenser;

public class StackOverflow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CupDispenser cd1 = new CupDispenser(5, "Los Angeles");
    CupDispenser cd2 = new CupDispenser(10, "New York");

    System.out.println(cd1.toString());
    System.out.println(cd2.toString());

    cd1.setNumberOfCups(7);
    cd1.setLocationOfCups("Toronto");

    cd2.decrementCups();
    cd2.decrementCups();

    System.out.println(cd1.toString());
    System.out.println(cd2.toString());
}

}
```